# how to set speed on a object xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode5

i having a bug I'm my app they my ball can get very slob or very fast. is it a if statement that can set the ball in the same speed all the time??

like this.

```
if (ball.speed < 5) {
ball.speed = 5
}

if (ball.speed > 5) {
ball.speed = 5
}
```

I am using a NSTimer to move the ball

```
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.01 target:self selector:@selector(BallMovement) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

***how do I define the .speed????***

Comment: Your post doesn't make much sense. We need a lot more background. What is a ball object? What is the speed property? How are you animating your ball? using Core animation or some other method? If you don't have code that changes the ball speed, how does it change from 5 to some other value? As the other poster said, your code might as well just set ball.speed to 5 directly, since both parts of the if statement do the same thing.

Comment: 'ball.speed == 5' doesn't set the value to 5 it just checks if the value is five. It should be ball.speed = 5.

Answer (score 2):

```
int minSpeed = ...;
int maxSpeed = ...;

if (ball.speed < minSpeed) {
    ball.speed = minSpeed;
} 
else if (ball.speed > maxSpeed) {
    ball.speed = maxSpeed;
}
```

BTW, your pseudocode above is equivalent to just one line:

```
ball.speed = 5;
```

;)

Comment: where should I write this code? in the ball movement???

Comment: I just get "property speed not found on object of type UIImageView"

Comment: This code should go wherever you want to control the ball's speed. I don't know where that is in your app.

Comment: how do I define the .speed? "property speed not found on object of type UIImageView"

Comment: If you get that error when you type ball.speed = whatever then ball must be a UIImageView. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

If ball is an `UIImageView` then it doesnot have a property named '`speed`' therefore you cannot use `ball.speed` in your code. You can use something like this to perform animation

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ball.png"]];
CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
transition.duration = 10.0f;
transition.type = kCATransitionMoveIn;
transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
[imageView.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];
```